# Type conversion in expression for NVARCHAR(200) may affect SeekPlan in query plan choice

Tags: sql, sql-server

> Type conversion in expression
>   (isnull([Employee].[EmployeeCode],[@Code])=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(200),[name], 0)) may affect "SeekPlan" in query plan choice

`@Code` and `[Employee].[EmployeeCode]` are both of type `nvarchar(200)`.

How can we remove this warning message from the SQL Server execution plan?

Comment: This has some discussion that might help http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36097/type-conversion-in-expression-may-affect-cardinalityestimate-in-query-plan-cho or http://thomaslarock.com/2012/08/why-datatypes-matter-3-ways-they-can-hurt-performance/

Comment: **"so how do we fix that problem? Simple, we help the optimizer to avoid the implicit conversion by giving it a more correct datatype".** I am using same data type for both, still warning comes. I can ignore it, but is there any clear way to remove this warning?

Answer (score 2):

What data type is [name]? You appear to have isnull([Employee].[EmployeeCode],[@Code])=[name] in a join or where clause. The implicit conversion is occurring on [name]. I suspect [name] is a varchar.

Comment: ** (isnull([Employee].[EmployeeCode],[@Code])** is an expression that says that IMPLICIT_CONVERSION is needed and denoted as '[Name]'